# Kendo TreeView in grid display 'undefined'

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-treeview

I had this [kendo grid demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/InigIPAX), and on `outletID` column, i want to use kendoTreeView with checkbox, so multiple selected `outletID` possible. But when edit it display **undefined** result, and the template that display `outletName` also not working. Appreciate your help

[DEMO IN DOJO](https://dojo.telerik.com/InigIPAX)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tree needs [dataTextField](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdowntree/configuration/datatextfield) and [dataValueField](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdowntree/configuration/datavaluefield) set.

Your column template doesn't know where to look for the outletName. Kendo supports [1-N relationships](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/foreignkeycolumn), but I'm not aware of N-N.

The data in your template is the current row of the grid. For the first row, that would be `{"id":"1","outletID":"LA2,LA3","accountName":"Data1"}`. You need to process that data yourself. For instance:

```
template: "#= (data.outletID) ? data.outletID.split(',')
    .map(x => TreeData.find(y => y.outletID == x)['outletName']) : '' #"
```

For the editor, the value of a dropDownTree is [an array](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdowntree/methods/value). Your row has a string. You need to do two things:

1 . Init the editor's value in the function `outletTree`:

```
if (options.model) {
    ddt.value((options.model[options.field] || '').split(','))
}
```

2 . When the dropDownTree's value changes, update your grid row:

```
  change: e => {
    const value = e.sender.value();
    console.log(value)
    options.model.set(options.field, value.join(','))
  }
```

Here's an updated dojo: https://dojo.telerik.com/@GaloisGirl/oYEGerAK . The "Update" button doesn't work yet, probably because the dataSource must support edition. [Here](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datasource/local-operations) is how to do it on local data.

Comment: Your answer is good and probably correct. But you need to provide the solution, like an update on OP's dojo or a code example. Using only external links is not a good practice.

Comment: @GaloisGirl and @DontVoteMeDown thanks for the response and `dataTextField / dataValueField` solution, but seem I still having trouble with the template not display `outletName` and not even checked, Need help, here I  [update my demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/InigIPAX/4)

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown it was wrong, I overlooked the fact that OP had an N-N relationship and not 1-N. I updated my answer.

Comment: @GaloisGirl Based on your demo, any idea why when I `unchecked` outletName it not update? , but when I `check` or add outletName it works fine. [update demo with working Update](https://dojo.telerik.com/OyuMocEy)

Comment: and if I check and unchecked again within same outletName.. a duplicate data will occur

Comment: Remove the name from `<input id="outletID" name="outletID" />` - it causes Kendo to do its own binding and interfere with ours.

Comment: @GaloisGirl at template any idea how to have a space after comma on each `outletName`. Example `OUTLET 2, OUTLET 3`

Comment: @dontbannedmeagain add a space to the separator:  `.join(', ')` and split accordingly.